# onmouseenter - Dynamic function variable for each new element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attaching elements created by Javascript inside a for loop.
What I'm trying to achieve is different variables passed to a function for each element.

Here's my code:

```
var thumbnail_box = document.createElement("div");
thumbnail_box.onmouseenter = function(){show_new_attachement_toolbar(total_upload)};
thumbnail_box.onmouseleave = function(){hide_new_attachement_toolbar(total_upload)};
```

the variable ***total_upload*** is automatically incremented in the end of each loop, however when all the elements are added, the function only triggers for the final value of ***total_upload*** instead of separate value for each element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple fix would be to wrap that code in an IIFE:

```
(function(x) {
  var thumbnail_box = document.createElement("div");
  thumbnail_box.onmouseenter = function () { show_new_attachement_toolbar(x) };
  thumbnail_box.onmouseleave = function () { hide_new_attachement_toolbar(x) };
})(total_upload);
```

You might need to read [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch3.md#blocks-as-scopes)

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm & I'm reading the link as well.